# Using Javascript regular expression for filtering HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex, filtering

Good morning

is there a clever way to use a **javascript** regular expression to clean up this string:

```
var spans = "<SPAN><A href="javascript:sel.RemoveProductFromSelection('12372');"><IMG src="remove.gif" width=18> </A>Mirage - JOY</SPAN>
<SPAN><A href="javascript:sel.RemoveProductFromSelection('12427');"><IMG src="remove.gif" width=18> </A>Nikon - D40 </SPAN>
<SPAN><A href="javascript:sel.RemoveProductFromSelection('12438');"><IMG src="remove.gif" width=18> </A>Mitsuca - DS 6083 </SPAN>"
```

and produce a resulting array like this:

```
var filtered = ["12372","12427","12438"];
```

the source html string in `spans` variable could be indented or not.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the string initially part of the document?  It would probably be easier to extract the values while they are still in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest matching just the script portion. Something like this:

```
regex = /RemoveProductFromSelection\('(\d+)'\)/g;

while (match = regex.exec(spans)) {
   console.dir(match);
}
```

note: I've used `console.dir()` here to output the results in an easy to read format. `console.dir()` is a debugging function in Firebug; if you're not using Firebug, you'll need to use a different method to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Spudley, here is what I've got so far

```
var filtered= spans.match(/\('(\d+)'\)/g);
for (var k=0;k<filtered.length;k++){
   filtered[k] = filtered[k].match(/\d+/g);
   alert(filtered[k]);
}
```